# XPages getEntryCount vs getAllEntries().getCount()

Tags: view, count, xpages

I have a view with 59 documents. I verified this in the client. In the beforePageLoad event of my XPage I have the following code:

```
var db:NotesDatabase =     session.getDatabase(sessionScope.serverPath,sessionScope.dbName);
var v:NotesView = db.getView(sessionScope.allEntriesView);
viewScope.vwEntryCount = v.getEntryCount();
viewScope.vwCollCount = v.getAllEntries().getCount();
```

[image: XPages debugger screenshot]

As you can see from the screenshot below, the collection count is correct but the getEntryCount has 3 more documents than I see in the view.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution.

I unchecked Show response documents in a hierarchy and on the third tab, checked the Don't show empty categories property. Once I did that, both counts came up to 62. The three extra documents were rep conflicts.

[image]

[image]