# Java IBM Lotus Notes retrive data from view fails in the middle due to null object

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I am trying to retrieve data from lotus notes database view using a java program. Below is my code:

```
int resultsCount = view.getEntryCount();
print("Results found in view = " + resultsCount);           

Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();
if (doc != null) {
    int count = 1;  
    while (count <= resultsCount) {
        count++;
        try {
            doc = view.getNextDocument(doc);
            if (doc == null) {
                print("Record " + count + " error. Null object.");  
            } 
        } catch (NotesException e) {
                print("Record " + count + " error. Exception.");
        }
    }
}
else {
    print("Record " + count + " error. Null object.");
}
```

I get below results:
*Results found in view = 1567

Record 866 error. Null object.*

Why is there a null document found when actually 1567 records present in the db view?
How can I resume to get rest of the records, because view.getNextDocument(doc) fails with Notes Exception after this happens.

Comment: Are you using ODA or did you miss the recycle()

Comment: @umeli I do recycle. This is fixed now after using view.getAllEntries().getCount();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using

```
int resultsCount = view.getAllEntries().getCount();
```

instead of

```
int resultsCount = view.getEntryCount();
```

Using view.getAllEntries().getCount() returns the actual entry count which is 866. I am not sure what view.getEntryCount() returns. But it is definitely not the actual document count.

Edit:
As mentioned in [XPages getEntryCount vs getAllEntries().getCount()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165307/xpages-getentrycount-vs-getallentries-getcount)  *view.getEntryCount()* includes replications and save conflicts. Therefore to get actual record count needs to use *view.getAllEntries().getCount()*

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36165307/xpages-getentrycount-vs-getallentries-getcount

Comment: @MichaelRuhnau yes it seems view.getEntryCount() includes replications and save conflicts. Edited the answer.

Comment: It could also be something that moves a document out of the view while you're in the loop.  Also Documents are not the same as Entries.